# StringUtils for StringBuilders?

Tags: java, string, append, stringbuilder

i am working with a piece of code that have a StringBuilder where i will do an append of some data and then send an email with all the data. Here is the code:

```
StringBuilder stringBuild= new StringBuilder();

       for (int i = 0; i < variable.size(); i++) { //Unknown size, could be quite big
           stringBuild.append(thingsToDO((Map<String, Object>) variable.get(i)));
       }

       sendEmail(stringBuild);
   
    /**
     * @param stringBuild
     */
    private void enviarEmail(StringBuilder stringBuild)
    {
        if(StringUtils.isNotBlank(stringBuild)) {
               //Email OK
           } else {
               //Email with all errors
           }
    }
```

Is okay to use the StringUtils library for StringBuilders or there are better methods to work with StringBuilders?

I don´t have that much experience with StringBuilders so maybe i am missing something, any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to have the [Java API documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) and [StringUtils API documentation](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html) at hand so you can decide whether you really need one more dependency (Apache Commons Lang) or if you want to go with the native classes only.

There are two aspects you want to keep in mind: Maintainability and performance.
Maintainability means your code is easy to understand and modify.
Performance wise, you'd have to profile the result to see which solution is faster.

Comment: Yeah, the reason i am going for StringBuilder is performance wise. I think that it doesn´t have that much impact in maintainability but i don´t know if this is the best way to do it. I think that my main problem is that i don´t quite understand the difference between a String and a StringBuilder. i will keep looking in that direction. Thanks

Comment: Strings are considered immutable, so if you want to assemble string data you are definitely better off using a StringBuilder. But you may still run a small performance test to get an impression.

Comment: @Hiran are you sure that "definitely better off using a StringBuilder"  is still valid for actual Java versions?   Since Java 9 the compiler uses `ConcatFactory` and bootstrap methods for concatenation (instead of `StringBuilder` as before) - so it can be *better* to do usual string concatenation with `+` (also depends a lot of how *better* is defined)

Answer (score 1):

To generate a `String` out of many strings or join only a few strings which can be massive in size you need to use either `StringBuilder`, other built-in mechanisms like `String.join()`, `Collectors.joining()`, etc.

That allow to avoid creating multiple intermediate copies of the data, which would take place in case of plane string concatenation (because `String` is immutable, and each concatenation result in allocating a new array of bytes in memory and coping the previous data into it).

Regarding the usage of `StringUtils` from Apache Commons, you can validate any instance of `CharSequence` (`String`, `StringBuilder`, etc.). It is perfectly fine for that purpose.

But there's more to it. Both using and not using a particular library or framework has a cost. On one hand it gives you some advantages by offering some functionality, but on the hand you're introducing a dependency which has some consequences (dependencies need to be managed, sometimes updating a dependency might entail changing the code, you can also introduce a vulnerability, etc.). So you always have to compare the two costs. It's always a good idea to have as fewer dependancies in the project as possible.

In this particular example I don't see a reason to utilize `StringUtils` unless you're not using Apache Commons.

Here's an example with standard `String.isBlank()`:

```
String str = variable.stream()
    .map(e -> thingsToDO((Map<String, Object>) e))
    .collect(Collectors.joining());
        
if (!str.isBlank()) {
    // do the action
}
```